# Pyspark - Merge files having different schema into one main file

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have nine csv files which looks like this:

```
trans_1
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|store_location_key|product_key|collector_key|  trans_dt|sales|units|           trans_key|
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|              9807|83215400105|           -1|2015-09-09|42.72|    1|19815980756712015...|
|              9807| 6024538816|           -1|2015-10-28|27.57|    1|21718980756712015...|
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 2 rows

trans_2
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|store_location_key|product_key|collector_key|  trans_dt|sales|units|           trans_key|
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|              7296|85375900278|           -1|2015-06-26| 4.97|    1|12548729658922015...|
|              7296|81526001001| 139537965459|2015-05-01|44.48|    1|24990729650922015...|
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 2 rows

trans_3
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|store_location_key|product_key|collector_key|  trans_dt|sales|units|           trans_key|
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|              9807|83215400105|           -1|2015-09-09|42.72|    1|19815980756712015...|
|              9807| 6024538816|           -1|2015-10-28|27.57|    1|21718980756712015...|
+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 2 rows

trans_4
+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+----------------+
|collector_key|  trans_dt|store_location_key|product_key|sales|units|       trans_key|
+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+----------------+
|           -1| 6/26/2015|              8142| 4319416816| 9.42|    1|1.6945500000E+25|
|           -1|10/25/2015|              8142| 6210700491| 24.9|    1|3.4001800000E+25|
+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+----------------+
only showing top 2 rows

trans_5
+-------------+----------+------------------+---------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|collector_key|  trans_dt|store_location_key|    product_key|sales|units|           trans_key|
+-------------+----------+------------------+---------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|           -1|2015-10-28|              6973|999999999999513|  0.0|    1|31575569731182201...|
|           -1|2015-07-24|              6973|    77105810883| 8.53|    1|31216969731182201...|
+-------------+----------+------------------+---------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 2 rows

trans_6
+-------------+----------+------------------+----------------+-----+-----+----------------+
|collector_key|  trans_dt|store_location_key|     product_key|sales|units|        trans_id|
+-------------+----------+------------------+----------------+-----+-----+----------------+
|           -1|10/28/2015|              6973|1000000000000000|  0.0| null|3.1575600000E+25|
|           -1| 7/24/2015|              6973|     77105810883| 8.53| null|3.1217000000E+25|
+-------------+----------+------------------+----------------+-----+-----+----------------+
only showing top 2 rows

trans_7
+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|collector_key|  trans_dt|store_location_key|product_key|sales|units|            trans_id|
+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|           -1|2015-09-09|              9807|83215400105|42.72|    1|19815980756712015...|
|           -1|2015-10-28|              9807| 6024538816|27.57|    1|21718980756712015...|
+-------------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 2 rows

trans_8
+----------------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----+-----+----------------+
|     product_key|collector_key|  trans_dt|store_location_key|sales|units|        trans_id|
+----------------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----+-----+----------------+
|1000000000000000|           -1|10/28/2015|              6973| null|    1|3.1575600000E+25|
|     77105810883|           -1| 7/24/2015|              6973| null|    1|3.1217000000E+25|
+----------------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----+-----+----------------+
only showing top 2 rows

trans_9
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|product_key|collector_key|  trans_dt|store_location_key|sales|units|            trans_id|
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
| 4319416816|           -1|2015-06-26|              8142| 9.42|    1|16945481425160201...|
| 6210700491|           -1|2015-10-25|              8142| 24.9|    1|34001814221225201...|
+-----------+-------------+----------+------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

All of them are having same column but at different position. I use this code to read all the files but having error.

```
trans = spark\
    .read\
    .format("csv")\
    .option("inferSchema","true")\
    .option("header","true")\
    .load("/Users/xyz/Downloads/xyz/trans_fact*.csv")
```

I want to write a code in pyspark only where I can read all these files and merge them into one dataframe (csv) with right data under right order column.

Comment: https://jqmartin.info/2020/05/07/merging-csv-files-with-schema-drift-in-databricks/comment-page-1/?unapproved=345&moderation-hash=18df83e6dee7a7e0033e6379bff0ce58#comment-345

Answer (score 1):

You could load the csv files one by one, add probably missing columns, sort the columns and then union them:

```python
import os
def load_single_files(dir):    
    dirpath,_,files = next(os.walk(dir))
    for f in files:
        yield spark\
            .read\
            .format("csv")\
            .option("inferSchema","true")\
            .option("header","true")\
            .load(os.path.join(dirpath, f))

import collections
def add_missing_cols_in_order(df,unique_cols):
    missing_cols = {col:F.lit(None).alias(col) for col in unique_cols if col not in df.columns}
    existing_cols = {col:F.col(col) for col in unique_cols if col in df.columns}
    cols = dict(missing_cols, **existing_cols)
    cols = list(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(cols.items())).values())
    return df.select(cols)

dfs = list(load_single_files("testdata"))
unique_cols = sorted(set([col for cols in [df.columns for df in dfs] for col in cols]))
df = dfs[0]
df = add_missing_cols_in_order(df, unique_cols)

for next_df in dfs[1:]:
    df = df.union(add_missing_cols_in_order(next_df, unique_cols))
```

This approach will be slower than loading the files all at once as Spark will not read the files in parallel. Depending on the size of the files this might or might not be an issue.

*EDIT*: following [thebluephantom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6933993/thebluephantom) suggestion to include the logic that missing columns are added automatically.

Comment: I dont know why, but it is creating a 'trans_id' column by itself which is giving me an error.

Comment: do you have any idea where it is coming from ?

Comment: @SahilNagpal probably the files do not have all the same columns. If one of the files has an additional column `trans_id` you would see an error

Comment: https://jqmartin.info/2020/05/07/merging-csv-files-with-schema-drift-in-databricks/comment-page-1/?unapproved=345&moderation-hash=18df83e6dee7a7e0033e6379bff0ce58#comment-345